# PHP - Error para insertar masivamente elementos en MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, aws

Que tal grupo de Stack..

Tengo un script que corro en cron cada 30 minutos y se encarga de consultar a MariaDB cierta información, y si dicha información **no existe** entonces pasa a conectarse a REDIS y guarda dicho dato. Esto lo hago con la finalidad de generar IDs que me sirvan para insertarse en MariaDB en un futuro, y en vez de generar una función "random", mejor le pido los IDs a REDIS que ya están listos para usarse en la inserción de contenido en MariaDB.

Cada 30 minutos corre el script y empieza hacer su trabajo, pero cierta cantidad de veces o tiempo, denoto que sale este error:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /app/base.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /app/base.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given in /app/base.php on line 14
Error 01: Error para Conectarse a MySQL.PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /app/base.php on line 52
PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /app/base.php on line 497
```

Este error no sale todo el tiempo, solo cierta cantidad de veces que se hace la conexión... He cambiado la configuración del SCRIPT como la tenia:

```
-- ANTES
# cat script.php
<?php
define('SERVER', 'db.midominio.com');
....
...
..
?>

-- DESPUES
# cat script.php
<?php
define('SERVER', 'ec2-x-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
....
...
..
?>
```

Esto con la finalidad de evitarle a PHP resolver el HOST de forma general, ya que **db.midominio.com** no esta expuesto hacia internet, solamente dentro de la red de contenedores que tengo en AWS.

Pero aun así, **persiste el problema** :(

---------- UPDATE 03/08/2024, 20:22

A continuación comparto el script que ejecuto para insertar datos en REDIS, básicamente primero verifico que el dato a insertar NO exista el MariaDB (consultar_datos_general()), si no existe entonces lo guardo en redis (redisPush()), posteriormente compruebo el tamaño de la "key" en redis (redisPilaLen()) y si llegue al limite máximo deseado, dejo de insertar IDs y paso al siguiente "key".

```
<?php
    function consultar_datos_general( $base_t=NULL, $valores=NULL, $sel=NULL ) {
        if( !($link= mysqli_connect( SERVER, BASE_USR, BASE_PASS, BASE )) )
            echo 'Error 01: Error para Conectarse a MySQL.'. mysqli_error($link)

        $cons= mysqli_query( $link, "select ". $sel. " from ". $base_t. " where ". $valores. ";");

        if( !mysqli_num_rows($cons) )
            return 0;
        else {
            $tmp= mysqli_fetch_array($cons);
            return $tmp[strtoupper($var)];
        }
    }
    
    $prefijo= 'sandbox';

    $service= array( 
        0=>array("a"=>$prefijo.".ep:ids:facturas", "b"=>"FACTURAS", "c"=>"10000"), 
        1=>array("a"=>$prefijo.".ep:ids:folio", "b"=>"FOLIO", "c"=>"10000"),
        2=>array("a"=>$prefijo.".ep:ids:usuarios", "b"=>"USUARIOS", "c"=>"10000"), 
        3=>array("a"=>$prefijo.".ep:ids:proveedores", "b"=>"PROVEEDORES", "c"=>"10000"), 
        4=>array("a"=>$prefijo.".ep:ids:clientes", "b"=>"CLIENTES", "c"=>"1000"), 
        5=>array("a"=>$prefijo.".ep:ids:proveedores", "b"=>"PROVEEDORES", "c"=>"10000"), 
        6=>array("a"=>$prefijo.".ep:ids:compras", "b"=>"COMPRAS", "c"=>"10000"), 
        7=>array("a"=>$prefijo.".ep:ids:reportes", "b"=>"REPORTES", "c"=>"10000"), 
        8=>array("a"=>$prefijo.".ep:ids:queueworks", "b"=>"QUEUE_WORKS", "c"=>"10000")
    );

    // Funciones de interes
    // redisPilaLen() <--- retorna el tama~o de la pila de los datos en REDIS
    // redisPush() <--- ingresa el dato a REDIS
    // generar_idtrack() <--- genera una semilla o dato aleatorio

    foreach( $service as $k=>$v ) {
        echo "\nServicio: ". $v["a"]. ", posee: ". $sysMbox->redisPilaLen($v["a"]). " / ". $v["c"];
        
        if( ($sysMbox->redisPilaLen($v["a"]))<$v["c"] ) { # es menor que el requerido
            $need= ($v["c"]-($sysMbox->redisPilaLen($v["a"])));
            $tmpId= array();

            do {
                do {
                    $id_track= generar_idtrack(); # generamos
                }while( !strcmp($id_track, consultar_datos_general($v["b"], "ID='". $id_track. "'", "ID")) || $tmpId[$id_track] || !$id_track );

                $sysMbox->redisPush($v["a"], $id_track);
                echo "\nGuardando ". $v["a"]. " para ". $v["b"]. " > ". $id_track;
                $tmpId[$id_track]= 1;
                unset($id_track);
            } while( $sysMbox->redisPilaLen($v["a"])<$v["c"] );
            unset($tmpId);
        }
    }
?>
```

Saludos !

Comment: mmm lamentablemente no podemos reproducir el error y el codigo o configuracion que utilizas nos da muy poca informacion como para decirte algo mas haya de lo que es evidente segun los warning que se muestran...

Comment: pero .... si mas no me equivoco pareciera que la coneccion se estan solapando ... pero no veo tampoco como manejas los errores de conexion debes tener algun codigo similar a este: `die("Error al conectar a la base de datos MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());`

Comment: ahora te recomendaria migrar a PDO XD

Comment: as intentando hacer las query con menos registros y ejecutarlos varias veces?

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover agregui el script que ejecuto...

Comment: no metas  consultar datos dentro de las condiciones... es como si intentaras en microsegudos miles de conecciones a la base de datos... la conexión de prepara una sola vez y se reutiliza hasta que ya no la necesites y se destruye...

Comment: Una pregunta, si "dicha información" no existe, por qué mejor no generar un uuid como identificador del registro en el momento de insertarlo en "un futuro'. No entiendo del todo la verdad.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover  Sucede que mi BDD no tiene un "ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT",ya que recibo mas de 100mil conexiones dentro de una hora y eso al momento de insertar el dato teniendo AUTO_INCREMENT me elevaba demasiado el uso del CPU y RAM, del servidor RDS (MariaDB en AWS), asi que, testeando me tope conque si EVITABA el AUTO_INCREMENT y simplemente insertaba el dato, eso bajaba mas de 70% del consumo del CPU y RAM.

Comment: sigo pensando que el error esta en como las planteado la logica de tu script ... estas creandu una coneccion por cada iteraccion lo que puede llegar a solaparlas ... en teoria yo haria algo como $conexcion; Loop(){.... logica...}; destruccion de conexion...

Comment: cual es la linea 52 de tu codigo ... el que es mencionado  en el error ???

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover asi que, para evitar AUTO_INCREMENT, tuve que optar por "algo" que me generara esos IDs aleatorios irrepetibles, y es donde entra REDIS, creo una base de los IDs generados por una instancia aparte usando cron. Es instancia crea 1 millon de registros y los deja guardados en REDIS.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover la linea 52 es el "unset"

Comment: no tiene sentido ... eso de que en una hora tienes 100,000 conexiones a la base de datos, entonces esta mal planteada la arquitectura ...

Comment: la linea 52 no puede ser el unset si el error dice que es la de mysqli... lo que dices no concuerda con el codigo ... a menos que lo hayas cambiado  y corrido ...

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover explicado asi rapido es: El cron ejecuta el array de $service, donde cada variable "a" es el nombre del "key" en REDIS. Se crea un ciclo que recorre el $service cada Key, si la Key tiene el tama~o que buscamos "variable c", entonces terminamos y vamos a la proxima Key. Cuando una Key no cumple el tama~o indicado en "c", entonces generamos un ID aleatorio y lo insertamos a la"key" de REDIS. Volvemos a checar el tama~o hasta alcanzar el valor de "c".

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover lo que pasa es que no es un servicio WEB, sino un servicio API, donde recibimos la conexion, se genera un documento electronico y se retorna la respuesta. Y asi, suceden muchisimas conexiones a la vez de diversos clientes intentando generar documentos electronicos.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover generalmente 1 cliente de nosotros puede lanzar 100 hilos, donde cada hilo es un requerimiento de 100 documentos electronicos, y esos 100 hilos llegan al mismo tiempo a nuestra API. No es de que cada cliente de nosotros tenga la "organizacion" de lanzar conexion por conexion, sino que lanzando todo de golpe generalmente.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover estoy copiando y pegando el codigo de ejemplo que puse en este post, y la linea 52 es la llamada al UNSET.

Comment: esto me huele a un servicio de facturacion electronica

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover si, eso es...

Comment: Creo que lo mas combeniente es utilizar un algoritmo que genere los ID y que los mas conveniente es utilizar un procedimiento almacenado que genere los ID en la tabla no tiene sentido eso de estar peleandoce con inserts y generarlos en otro sistema ...